# Vue.js - Parent generate component based on renderless child data

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-class-components

I am trying to create a button generation system using **vue 3** and **vue-class-component**, where the expectation is as follows: (note that the amount of buttons given is not static, meaning it could be 1 or many)

#### Input

```js
<ButtonGroup id="bg1">
    <Button text="button1" url="./location1" />
    <Button text="button2" url="./location2" />
    ...
</ButtonGroup>
```

Here the `Button` is renderless and the `ButtonGroup` first gets all its childrens data to do preprocessing, like setting the primary button, before rendering the whole shebang, resulting in something like:

#### Output

```html
<div id="bg1" class="button-group">
    <a href="./location1" class="button primary">button1</a> 
    <a href="./location2" class="button">button2</a> 
    ...
</div>
```

The code for the `Button` and `ButtonGroup` class look like

```js
// File Button.vue
@Options({})
export default class Button extends Vue {
    @Prop() text!: string | undefined
    @Prop({default:""}) url!: string
}

// File ButtonGroup.vue
@Options({})
export default class ButtonGroup extends Vue { // This is the rendering class
    @Prop() id: string | undefined
    buttons: Array<Button> = [] // Contains buttons so it can be dynamically rendered

    beforeCreated(){ // Or created or so. 
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I am fully aware that, making this in Vue 3, accessing children has become quite difficult, but this would be the most easy option I think. How do I get this to work?

The alternative would be that `Button` would create the `<a>` tag and afterwards `ButtonGroup` would add the primary to the according tag, but that strikes me as even more complicated and as I have some other elements alike awaiting the same treatment as the buttons, I would probably get stuck somewhere down the road again.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [render function API](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/render-function-api.html#overview) in Vue? This is probably what you need to use.

Comment: I looked at that, but that would render the `Button` component, which, beside the fact that at this moment it even refuses to render inside the `ButtonGroup` container, would mean that it is not renderless

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before when using `href` to navigate through pages in Vue.

I recommend you change the `<a href="./location1"/>` to `<router-link to="./location1"/>`

Comment: Will do, thanks! However it does not solve the question at hand.